# How create NTLM Authentification with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, ntlm

Since 23 sdk Android class were excluded classes:

```
org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme;
org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory;
org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMScheme;
org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngine;
org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineException;
```

As it is now authorized in AD, with login and password through a retrofit? There OKHttpklient can be through headers?

Answer (score 2):

1) add package **org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5** to build.gradle (app)

```
//noinspection DuplicatePlatformClasses
implementation '**org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5**'
```

2) Add package ***org.apache.http.impl.auth*** to your project (folder in /java)

3) Create public class in added ***org.apache.http.impl.auth*** package

```
public class PublicNTLMEngineImpl implements NTLMEngine {
  // with content of http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.5.2/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/auth/NTLMEngineImpl.java
}
```

4) use Giohji's ***NTLMAuthenticator*** with instance of new ***PublicNTLMEngineImpl***

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .authenticator(new NTLMAuthenticator(username, password, domainOrComputerName))
                .build();
```

5) source code: 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.5.2/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/auth/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [okhttp's github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/206).
It was posted by [SelvinPL](https://github.com/SelvinPL).

First you have to implement the NTLM authenticator (it uses NTLMEngineImpl, a standalone version of [org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.3.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/auth/NTLMEngineImpl.java), which was also created by [SelvinPL](https://github.com/SelvinPL)). The code below is a slightly modified version of [SelvinPL](https://github.com/SelvinPL)'s implementation to run on the latest retrofit's version (2.1.0).

```
private static class NTLMAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    final NTLMEngineImpl engine = new NTLMEngineImpl();
    private final String domain;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String ntlmMsg1;

    private NTLMAuthenticator(String username, String password, String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        String localNtlmMsg1 = null;
        try {
            localNtlmMsg1 = engine.generateType1Msg(null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ntlmMsg1 = localNtlmMsg1;
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        final List<String> WWWAuthenticate = response.headers().values("WWW-Authenticate");
        if (WWWAuthenticate.contains("NTLM")) {
            return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", "NTLM " + ntlmMsg1).build();
        }
        String ntlmMsg3 = null;
        try {
            ntlmMsg3 = engine.generateType3Msg(username, password, domain, "android-device", WWWAuthenticate.get(0).substring(5));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", "NTLM " + ntlmMsg3).build();
    }
}
```

Then you can register the authenticator like this example:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .authenticator(new NTLMAuthenticator(username, password, domain))
            .build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getURL(context))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
return retrofit.create(Api.class);
```

It works for com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0.

Comment: NTLMEngineImpl - not support in 23 sdk

Comment: Why are you passing null in domain when generating type1Msg?

Comment: What is **NTLMEngineImpl** and where to get the gradle dependency??